# Cannot get FetchType.EAGER to work with @ElementCollection

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading, eager-loading, transactional

I have the following annotations on a variable:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@CollectionTable(name = "question_translation",
                 foreignKey = @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT, name = "fk_question_translation_question"),
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "question_id"))
@MapKeyColumn(name = "language", nullable = false)
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "translation", nullable = false)
private Map<Language, String> translations;
```

When I do `translations.get(Language.EN)` outside a `@Transactional` I get: 
`org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session`

Versions:

```
spring boot: <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
<hibernate.version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>1.0.2.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>
```

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

After searching a bit further, I think the problem is because I use spring-data and their repositories... They seem to ignore the fetch type...

Answer (score 1):

I know what is wrong: spring-data ignores fetch types until you specify a @EntityGraph annotation on both the method in the repository and the entity.

The f*cked up part is that you cannot override a method from JpaRepository and add @EntityGraph to it, because it is ignored.

You need to write your own methods in your repository... e.g.:

```
@EntityGraph(value = "graphNameDefinedOnEntity", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
QuestionEntity getById(Long id);
```

This greatly conflicts with `getOne(Long id)` provided by `JpaRepository`. Extremely confusing. So it might be better to just name it `getByIdEagerlyLoaded` and write the query yourself with `@Query` annotation